# How to record all errors generated from a model method in a log file in Rails 3.2

Tags: logging, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following code and I want to write any errors generated when running it to a log file.

How can I do that in rails?

```
def get_score
 if status == "approved" 
       begin 
          metrics = Popularity.get_metrics(url,nil ,:resource)

            update_column(:metrics, metrics.to_yaml)
            update_column(:score,Popularity.score(metrics,:resource ))
            reputation = reputations.build(:metrics => metrics)
            reputation.score = score
            reputation.save

       rescue
       #write the error that was raised to a log file
       end   
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this

```
 def get_score
  if status == "approved" 
       begin 
          metrics = Popularity.get_metrics(url,nil ,:resource)

            update_column(:metrics, metrics.to_yaml)
            update_column(:score,Popularity.score(metrics,:resource ))
            reputation = reputations.build(:metrics => metrics)
            reputation.score = score
            reputation.save

       rescue => e
          Rails.logger.debug "Opps Error Occurred -- > #{e} "
       end   
    end
```

The `Rails.logger.debug` will log the error in the `log/[your environment].log`

with a `debug` tag alternatively you can also used

`Rails.logger.info  "Opps Error Occurred -- > #{e} "`